# how can i create cluster in vsphere 5.5?

Tags: vsphere-client

how can I open the cluster creating interface!

this is what just was showed with me:

[my interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HVv3.png)

Comment: Do you have Vcenter server?

Comment: vsphere-client 5.5

Comment: I am asking about Vcenter server. You need a Vcenter server for clustering.

Comment: please , do u have any direct link that i can download it? cause i am trying with goolge but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 4):

Right, you need vCenter to create a cluster. Download the latest vCenter from here: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VC650&productId=614&rPId=13344
And this is the guide on getting started with vCenter: http://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/vmware-vcenter-server6-deployment-guide-white-paper.pdf